# Debugging mysql query executed using bash file and nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, bash, cron

i'm trying to create a cron job to insert data into table, but it is not working and i cant even find a way to debug it properly.
the idea is quite basic: get path of file, post it and execute the `script.sh` file. the script loops over the file's content and insert them to the db.

the HTML input part very simple:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:9080/config" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="data" style="width: 500px;">
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="config"></input>
</form>
```

and the `server.js` processing is also quite basic (i am leaving the cron implementation out cause it is working and unnecessary for my question):

```
app.post('/config', function (req, res) {
    var source = req.body.data;
    var script = ' /home/al/Downloads/DataMining/node.js/script.sh ' + source; //file not found -> full path of source file
    exec(script);
    addCronTab(script);
    //readFile - response file that read..
    res.end(script);
});
```

i think that the problem comes here in my bash file:

```
#! /bin/bash


config=$(date +%s)

#copying what in target to $config ( example: $config = 11444345)
rsync -rvzh $1 /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/target > /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/$config

countC=0
countS=`wc -l /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/$config | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'`
let countS--
let countS--
let countS--

while read LINEC #read line (file? countS!)
do  
    if [ "$countC" -gt 0 ]; then
        if [ "$countC" -lt "$countS" ]; then

            FILENAME="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/target/"$LINEC
            count=0
            countW=0

            while read LINE
            do
                for word in $LINE;
                do 
                    echo "INSERT INTO data_mining.data (word, line, numWordLine, file) VALUES ('$word', '$count', '$countW', '$FILENAME');" >> /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/query
                    mysql -u root -password< /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/query
                    echo > /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/query
                    let countW++
                done
                countW=0
                let count++
            done < $FILENAME
            count=0

            rm -f /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/query
            rm -f /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/$config

        fi
    fi
    let countC++
done < /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/$config #finish while
```

i have files with text in a Dir, i passed this Dir path (in every way possible...) to config but for some reason nothing goes into the database.

any idea what am i missing? or how can i debug it? by debug i mean checking if and what query the script executed, or even simply echo from the bash file.....any idea is highly appreciated, thx.

Comment: Paste your script in http://www.shellcheck.net/ to see some major problems. Before going deep into it, the lack of quotes is a risk. Also, consider giving a sample input together with its expected output, so that we can debug the bash script better.

Comment: you could run the shell script in debug verbose mode by adding `-vx` to the shabang line. It would print each line with its variables substituted before running it.